# Looking for a suffix to denote paraphernalia associated with a person

Tags: single-word-requests, suffixes

Can someone help me identify the below-described suffix.  I feel I've seen it before, but I can't bring it to mind or locate it through my usual methods (i.e., search queries).

The suffix is added to the end of a person's name and denotes paraphernalia, collectibles, memorabilia or other items associated with that person.  For example, if someone is obsessed with Richard Nixon, and owns a bunch of Nixon's old letters, belongings, who knows, clothes, tape recordings, etc., you might refer to this collection as Nixon + a suffix.  Like -ica, or -ia.  Nixonica.  But that's not right, I don't think.

In any event, the effect might be facetious (or not).  The suffix might also apply to items associated with a non-person, but I can't remember.  It may also only work with certain names - for example, those that end in a consonant.

Comment: "Nixonia" maybe? Thinking of "memorabilia."

Comment: ew ... a Nixon obsession?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have got to be looking for the suffix "-*ana*".

> (SOED) **-ana** Forming plural nouns with the sense 'publications or other items concerning or associated with a person, place, or topic' as *Americana, cricketana, railwayana, Shakespeariana, Victoriana*.

Comment: Yes - ana, or iana.  That's the ticket!  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A possible alternative to "ana" is "-alia", although it doesn't seem to be widely listed in dictionaries:

> **-alia**
> *Suffix*
> (forming plural nouns) denoting items associated with a particular area of activity or interest.
> Example *kitchenalia*  [[Lexico]](https://www.lexico.com/definition/-alia)

and on *affixes.org*

> **-alia** A collection or group ... sometimes with implications of triviality...  [[Affixes]](https://www.affixes.org/alpha/a/-alia.html)

However, neither "kitchenalia" nor "-alia" as a suffix is listed in my 1975 copy of the Concise Oxford Dictionary (Edition 6).

To my ear I would use "Nixonalia" as a portmanteau for items collected because of an association with Nixon (but not "Nixonana"), but would collectively describe items typical of the Victorian era as "Victoriana".